# Custom animation react navigation bottom tab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a shrink animation with Stack Navigator, on snack, https://snack.expo.io/hvv8URsmp , but I haven't been able to replicate it with createBottomTabNavigator.

I saw some github threads that say it's not supported in the same way Stack Navigator is, with this link showing how to do it manually with Animated https://github.com/brentvatne/animated-bottom-navigation-example/blob/master/createAnimatedBottomTabNavigator.js.

While it seems to work, I would love it if I could separate the animation code out into my navigator file, as shown in the snack, rather than be hardcoded into my screen component like in the second link.

Is there a way to migrate the code that I already have working for the stack navigator into an existing bottomTabNavigator?